# Assembly,input with keyboard

Tags: assembly

I wrote the program on Asemby, that read input of symvols with keyboard.My task:
Enter from the keyboard string (late entry sign - the symbol "*").I don't know how I need to do this.This is my code:

```
cseg segment
assume cs:cseg, ds:cseg
org 100h
start:
mov ah, 0ah
lea dx, buffer
int 21h
xor ah, ah
int 16h
ret
buffer   db       100
blength  db       ?
_str:
cseg ends
end start
```

Comment: It means that if I input * symbol that the entering of symbols will end

Comment: And what do you want to do with other symbols? The interrupt you're using inputs an entire string from the user. You probably wanted `int 21h` with `ah = 01h` to read a character, not `ah = 0ah` which reads an entire string.

Comment: You could read the characters one-by-one (`int 21h` / `ah= 01h`) and stop when you get a `'*'`.

Comment: Have you tried to run your code at all? If you do a little research and try some things based upon that research, you should be able to make some progress.

Comment: If the input of symbols will end my program must output my symbols by default and in reverse